# Running Access queries : "Syntax Error in From Clause" Error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to run a query in Microsoft Access in Excel VBA. I get the error "Syntax Error in FROM Clause". Where am I going wrong?

```
Dim conn as ADODB.connection
Dim thisSQL as string
thisSQL = "SELECT Column FROM QueryName WHERE [Column] = Test;"
Set conn = new ADODB.Connection
with conn
.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:\AXIS Conversion\FIA FAS 133 Documentation\AVRF Validation\AVRF Testing Database.accdb;"
.open
.execute thissql, ,adcmdtext
```

I've tried many variation in my SQL code by adding/removing semi colon, adding/removing brackets, etc.
Thanks!

Comment: Table has field named "Column"? If [Column] is a text type field, need apostrophe delimiters: `WHERE [Column]='Test';"`. Also, Execute is for action SQL (DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE). Need a recordset object for SELECT.

Comment: Also, Column is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names. If you do, enclose in [ ].

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing the column value incorrectly.
Try putting value Test in single quote as

thisSQL = "SELECT Column FROM QueryName WHERE [Column] = 'Test';"

Instead of

thisSQL = "SELECT Column FROM QueryName WHERE [Column] = Test;"

Also verify running the same query in access directly.

Comment: Answer is only partial solution as there are multiple issues with code.